# sslv3 alert handshake failure with openSSL and python requests

Tags: tls, python

I'm having issues invoking a RESTful API secured via mutual SSL.

I have no issues invoking the API in SOAPUI after providing the keystore with the private and public key to use for mutual SSL.

In a python script, I'm using below snippet to perform the mutual SSL (via requests library):

```
class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
""""Transport adapter" that allows us to use SSLv3."""

def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
    self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
        num_pools=connections, maxsize=maxsize,
        block=block, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
...
s = requests.session()
s.mount("https://", MyAdapter())
req = s.post(
    downstreamURL, data=payload, 
    headers=headers, verify=False,
    cert=("C:\\Users\\garamirez\\Documents\\public.pem",   "C:\\Users\\garamirez\\Documents\\key.key")
```

)

I've tested another API secured via mutual SSL via the above snippet and the requests library has no issues sending the client cert.

When I run my script, below error is shown:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'sslv3 alert handshake failure')],)",)

I ran a wireshark capture to compare the difference between a successful SOAPUI call and a failed python script call, and I'm not seeing why the python call is failing.  In both cases, the client and server agree to use the same protocol and cipher suite, but the python case fails right after "Certificate, Cleint Key Exchange, Certificate Verfiy, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake message" as shown below:

[image]

Successful SOAPUI sequence:
[image]

Per the wireshark capture, the back-end API supports only the AES128-SHA cipher via TLSv1.

Interestingly, openssl is also showing an SSLv3 handshake failure despite getting the full cert chain:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Symantec Corporation, OU = Symantec Trust Network, CN = Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Missouri, L = Saint Louis, O = TALX Corporation, OU = ASG, CN = test.ofx4.talx.com
verify return:1
4294956672:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1472:SSL alert number 40
4294956672:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:656:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Missouri/L=Saint Louis/O=TALX Corporation/OU=ASG/CN=test.ofx4.talx.com
   i:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE0DCCBDmgAwIBAgIQJQzo4DBhLp8rifcFTXz4/TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBf
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEXMBUGA1UEChMOVmVyaVNpZ24sIEluYy4xNzA1BgNVBAsT
LkNsYXNzIDMgUHVibGljIFByaW1hcnkgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkw
HhcNMDYxMTA4MDAwMDAwWhcNMjExMTA3MjM1OTU5WjCByjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
FzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQLExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVz
dCBOZXR3b3JrMTowOAYDVQQLEzEoYykgMjAwNiBWZXJpU2lnbiwgSW5jLiAtIEZv
ciBhdXRob3JpemVkIHVzZSBvbmx5MUUwQwYDVQQDEzxWZXJpU2lnbiBDbGFzcyAz
IFB1YmxpYyBQcmltYXJ5IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5IC0gRzUwggEi
MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCvJAgIKXo1nmAMqudLO07cfLw8
RRy7K+D+KQL5VwijZIUVJ/XxrcgxiV0i6CqqpkKzj/i5Vbext0uz/o9+B1fs70Pb
ZmIVYc9gDaTY3vjgw2IIPVQT60nKWVSFJuUrjxuf6/WhkcIzSdhDY2pSS9KP6HBR
TdGJaXvHcPaz3BJ023tdS1bTlr8Vd6Gw9KIl8q8ckmcY5fQGBO+QueQA5N06tRn/
Arr0PO7gi+s3i+z016zy9vA9r911kTMZHRxAy3QkGSGT2RT+rCpSx4/VBEnkjWNH
iDxpg8v+R70rfk/Fla4OndTRQ8Bnc+MUCH7lP59zuDMKz10/NIeWiu5T6CUVAgMB
AAGjggGbMIIBlzAPBgNVHRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MDEGA1UdHwQqMCgwJqAkoCKGIGh0
dHA6Ly9jcmwudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL3BjYTMuY3JsMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjA9
BgNVHSAENjA0MDIGBFUdIAAwKjAoBggrBgEFBQcCARYcaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmVy
aXNpZ24uY29tL2NwczAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUf9Nlp8Ld7LvwMAnzQzn6Aq8zMTMwbQYI
KwYBBQUHAQwEYTBfoV2gWzBZMFcwVRYJaW1hZ2UvZ2lmMCEwHzAHBgUrDgMCGgQU
j+XTGoasjY5rw8+AatRIGCx7GS4wJRYjaHR0cDovL2xvZ28udmVyaXNpZ24uY29t
L3ZzbG9nby5naWYwNAYIKwYBBQUHAQEEKDAmMCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8v
b2NzcC52ZXJpc2lnbi5jb20wPgYDVR0lBDcwNQYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMC
BggrBgEFBQcDAwYJYIZIAYb4QgQBBgpghkgBhvhFAQgBMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUA
A4GBABMC3fjohgDyWvj4IAxZiGIHzs73Tvm7WaGY5eE43U68ZhjTresY8g3JbT5K
lCDDPLq9ZVTGr0SzEK0saz6r1we2uIFjxfleLuUqZ87NMwwq14lWAyMfs77oOghZ
tOxFNfeKW/9mz1Cvxm1XjRl4t7mi0VfqH5pLr7rJjhJ+xr3/
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=Missouri/L=Saint Louis/O=TALX Corporation/OU=ASG/CN=test.ofx4.talx.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Symantec Corporation/OU=Symantec Trust Network/CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 1999 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign
---
SSL handshake has read 4660 bytes and written 338 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 734CAC5732452D935C1F5CDBC1900BB78E0805205013443C1B4D742D21B82FFD
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: BFCB8041D10B303310CADDCF6A987D96E8FE72A05B2D8499410E06B96A326AA6581455DCC5D3755443C4FCA550B7ED83
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1468510438
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Does anyone have any pointers on where I can look into here?

Comment: Those are likely just old routine names that are reused to write and read SSL data.  Clearly the wireshark capture shows TLSv1.

Comment: In both cases, wireshark indicates they're using tlsv1 and the same cipher, which is expected as the script is instructed to use it, but what I'm not understanding is why the python case is failing despite appearing to use the same cipher/protocol and client cert.  SOAPUI is not using a proxy to call the API, and the script does send the same client cert if i use the same code, but simply change the endpoint

Comment: Maybe more can be said if you provide the full packet captures and not just the screenshots. Then one could compare  the successful and unsuccessful traffic at the detailed protocol level.  But please make sure that you provide the capture with a full handshake in both cases, because in the SOAPUI case you show only the handshake of the session resume which misses the important information how the session was established in the first place.

Comment: One possible explanation is that you are using the wrong client certificate - but again this is hard to tell without having access to useful packet captures. Try cloudshark.org for uploading such captures.

Comment: Sure.  This is the non-working: http://www.filedropper.com/not-working and this is the working capture: http://www.filedropper.com/working

Comment: First filedropper doesn't work in my Firefox. Second as @Steffen noted your 'working' case is resumption of a previous session and does not include the working handshake. But looking at your 'non-working' case I see your client sent a cert issued by `CN = Symantec Class 2 Shared Intermediate Certificate Authority, OU = Class 2 Managed PKI Individual Subscriber CA` **BUT NOT the required 'chain' cert** for that intermediate. EE cert does have AIA.iss but only LDAP, and maybe the server doesn't support that (which is permitted) but your working case does have the chain cert. ...

Comment: ... I (too) don't do LDAP but found an apparent copy of this cert at https://www.globaltrustpoint.com/trustcenter-list.jsp under Verisign (NOT Symantec) which verifies under known-good Verisign class 2 public G3. If you want to test with `openssl s_client`, add that chain cert to your truststore or (usually better) a copy. (Yes the truststore; s_client uses libssl default logic instead of properly setting the chain.) And here where the server chain is valid, `-showcerts` is useless clutter that slows finding the real problem.

Answer (score 4):

According to the `openssl s_client` output the server accepts certificates issued by the following CA:

```
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=US/O=VeriSign...CN=VeriSign Class 1 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
/C=US/O=VeriSign...CN=VeriSign Class 2 Public Primary Certification Authority - G3
```

But the client certificate you send has the following issuer:

```
Issuer... CN=Symantec Class 2 Shared Intermediate Certificate Authority
```

This is not an issuer the server accepts. Since no intermediate certificates are send by the client which might result in a trusted chain to any of the two CA the server likes the handshake will fail.

My guess is that in the working version the client sends the leaf certificate and also an intermediate certificate so that the trust chain can be built. But since the pcap only contains a session reuse and not a full handshake this guess can not be verified based on the provided information.